# Mostrar ruas e imagens no Type Satellite por default

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou querendo mostrar os nomes das ruas e estabelecimentos por default. Qual seria a opção? Estou fazendo assim:

```
var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, centerLon),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas [opções do mapa](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions) não há propriedades para habilitar estas opções explicitamente, elas já vem com o tipo de visualização. Para exibir conforme você precisa, basta usar a visualização `HYBRID`, desta forma:

```
var options = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, centerLon),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
```

Veja um exemplo completo abaixo:

```js
var gm = google.maps;

function initialize() {
  var options = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new gm.LatLng(-27.593427, -48.550686),
    mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    scrollwheel: false
  };

  var map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

}

gm.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que declarar o tipo do mapa como `ROADMAP`, que é a opção padrão da API do MAPS.

Deixe assim:

```
var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, centerLon),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Comment: o ROADMAP mostra o nome das ruas e estabelecimentos, é isso que eu quero mas utilizando o Satellite.